# Calling a Jsonreader class for twitch streams

Tags: java, json, class

Ive encountered a little problem.

I made a json url checker that checks if a twitch.tv stream is either online or offline.
That one thing is handled in a seperate class TwitchLiveChecker.java.

Now i want to call that class with a timer all X minutes but somehow i dont understand how to call the class.

This is how i call it;

```
public void LiveChecker() {

    TTtwl.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
                TwitchLiveChecker.startup();     *<- THIS Doesnt work :(*


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(TwitchLiveChecker.json);
            System.out.println(TwitchLiveChecker.json);

          }
          }, 1000*10, 1000*10);
}
```

and this is my TwitchLiveChecker class File;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class TwitchLiveChecker {

    public static JSONObject json;

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void startup(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    json = readJsonFromUrl("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel="+MyBot.ownerchannel+"");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
}
```

Im thankful for any hints or examples on what im doing wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing parameters to a method that requires them.  Since `TwitchLiveChecker.startup()` doesn't use the `args` parameter, you should remove it. Your method signature should be `public static void startup(`), not `public static void  startup(String[] args)`

Also, threads and static data (specifically your `public static JSONObject json;` don't mix well.  Depending on what your thread pool is doing, you could have multiple threads writing to your static json object at the same time, corrupting the data in it.